# Load mysql data to Highcharts line chart using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts, linechart

I'm trying to import my data from a database to a line chart (Highcharts). My code doesn't work.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require('../php/config.php');
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ginnastica", "progetto");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
        if(isset($_GET['src']))
        {   
        $records=array();
        $records =  select($mysqli,"SELECT Sesso AS name, Occupati AS data FROM occupazione WHERE Sesso='totale' AND Periodo LIKE '%2008'");
            $rows = array();
            $rows['name'] = 'Totale';
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
            $rows['data'][]=$r['data'];
            }
            return json_encode($rows);
        }
        else
            return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'details' => 'no src provided'));

    }
?>
```

It seems that "mysql_fetch_assoc" doesn't work. The output of my array $rows id that:

```
{

    "name": "Totale"

}
```

There isn't an element called "data".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're missing a { after the else

Answer (score 0):

At first:

1. It would be worth to see what is in your `../php/config.php` file, because the content of that file may impact the behavior of other lines you provided.
2. The structure and data (at least few lines of data) of `occupazione` table is also worth to see, because data or structure could change the output as well.
3. You are missing a `{` after the `else`, - as @Moppo already mentioned.
4. Warning on `mysql_fetch_assoc`
   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. Read more in php.net

After that and some more fixes I would finally write your code in the way close to that:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ginnastica", "progetto");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_GET['src'])) {
    $records = $con->query("SELECT Sesso AS name, Occupati AS data FROM occupazione WHERE Sesso='totale' AND Periodo LIKE '%2008'");
    $rows = array();
    $rows['name'] = 'Totale';
    while ($r = $records->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows['data'][] = $r['data'];
    }
    return json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
} else {
    return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'details' => 'no src provided'));
}
```

As I said, we know nothing about database you work with, so my guess would be that your select returns no lines as a result. And then you got no `data` (only `{"name": "Totale"}`), just because `while` has nothing to iterate throw.